# "Layout Update XML" field in Magento2 admin is missing

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4

I installed a clean version of Magento 2.3.4 with composer and added a template. Then I wanted to edit some pages by inserting some XML code into the "Custom Layout XML" field that is visible in this screen:

[image: Admin with custom xml layout field]

But in my admin there is shown another field labeled "Custom Layout Update" not XML:

[image: Admin with custom layout update field]

The help tooltip says

> List of layout files with an update handle "selectable" matching
>   *PageIdentifier*_*UpdateID*. See Magento documentation for more information

But I can't find any information in the documentation and don't know how to enable the "Custom layout xml" field?

Comment: Please have read release notes from Magento: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/release-notes-2-3-4-open-source.html

Answer (score 8):

The functionality of custom layout updates was removed from Magento to remove the opportunity for Remote Code Execution, so there no way to return it back

see: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/release-notes-2-3-4-open-source.html

Comment: As of writing this, the Magento 2.3.4 release notes incorrectly link to the wrong documentation for this change. It should be linked to: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#create-cms-pageproductcategory-specific-layouts

Comment: When "custom layout update" was removed the column "Custom Layout Update" is still available in the database. In my case it contains all the XML changes I have previously inputted. And Magento is still using the XML changes to render the category pages. Having removed the XML input field and and using XML files moving forward, what should one do with the data in "Custom Layout Update"?

Comment: @KAndy sir, I have face same issue. How to apply different dfifferent list.phtml for each category. Could you please help me?

Comment: @user12208 Same here. Have you solved that? How?

Answer (score 7):

They go in `app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/Magento_Cms/layout/`

The file name should be like `cms_page_view_selectable_<url-key>_<name>.xml`

The ***name*** is just any name you want to give the layout. It will be used in the Custom Layout Update selection field in the Design section of the CMS Page edit page. But I noticed that, if the name is multiple words separated by "-" or "_" only the first word shows up in the selection box. So I'm naming them like "landingPage".

Comment: This is all correct, and just to add on to this answer, if the layout update is for the **homepage**, Magento currently (2.3.4) has a bug where the layout updates don't apply unless you also create the file cms_index_index_selectable_<url-key>_<name>.xml with the same content as your "cms_page_view" file. For more information see: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26758

Comment: it's working properly.

Comment: @DustinW Thank you, your comment helped me a lot!

Comment: Just want to reinforce the key word **ALSO** in the comment by @DustinW. You need 2 files in your `Magento_Cms/layout/` directory: 1) `cms_index_index_selectable_<url-key>_<name>.xml`; and 2) `cms_page_view_selectable_<url-key>_<name>.xml`. Wasted over an hour trying to get this to work before I read this comment and discovered the nuance here.

Comment: If you want to create Layout XML files that can apply to multiple pages, check out this extension https://github.com/integer-net/magento2-global-custom-layout

Answer (score 2):

I followed the same and put the xml in app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/layout/cms_page_view_selectable_home-page_homelayout.xml

After clearing the cache , i can see the value 'homelayout' in respective cms content edit area dropdown 'custom Layout Update' and updated the same.
But cannot see the layout update in frontend?

I used below content in xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.top">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="home_cusom">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">home_main_block</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
</referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Solved by following this link
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26758
It's bug in 2.3.4.

Answer (score 0):

According to release note, now to manage custom layout updates we should do that by creating a physical files, my question is how to do that? It’s not clear for me how to manage *PageIdentifier*_*UpdateID* and where to put the file.
Thanks for your kindly help

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a custom layout for category:

```
app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/Magento_Catalog/layout/
```

name : `catalog_category_view_selectable_3_custom.xml`

Not showing at all in the category ID:3 design tab ..

Any idea ?
Thank you

Comment: please check Content > Design > Configuration > Global Website is set to the theme you are adding catalog_category_view_selectable_x_custom.xml. and do not forget to clean cache.

Comment: not doing anything. I put the theme everywhere ... still can't add a custom layout.. see the link below .. nothing here :
(https://imgur.com/a/W79QjkM)

Comment: Please check if your xml well formed with no errors. Ir there is an error in the layout magento in production mode will not add it and just ignore it. In developer mode you will see error.

Comment: also the product sku must match with layout  name like this: catalog_product_view_selectable_2200-49710-019_custom.xml  when product sku is:2200-49710-019

Answer (score 0):

To further expand on KAndy's answer, if you need to add layout update to cms page with url key "my-first-cms-page" then you can create file

> cms_page_view_selectable_my-first-cms-page_LayoutUpdateName.xml

This file will go under `app/design/frontend/<them_vendor>/<theme_dir>/Magento_Cms/layout` directory.

When you go in the admin panel, under "Design" => Custom Layout Update you will see LayoutUpdateName" in the dropdown. Select and clear cache and your layout updates will be applied to the page.

Comment: Is there any possibility to remove all the CMS page header section cache?