# Layout Update XML for Category in Magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

Can anyone help me how to change number of products per page for a SPECIFIC category. I am on magento 2.3.4 and noticed that Layout Update XML does not exist anymore.

Comment: Chech my answer

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the following question and it's answer to help you out. 
[How to add/update custom layout update on magento 2.3.4](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/302775/77840)

Answer (score 0):

Add your set number of products in `Admin->Store->Configuration->Catalog->Storefront->Products per Page on Grid Allowed Values` and `Products per Page on List Allowed Values`,

For example, if you want to set **6** for any category add the value like the below screenshot:

[image]

Then go to a particular category in which you want to change the number of products per page and add below code in `Design->Layout Update XML`

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar">
            <action method="setDefaultListPerPage">
                <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">6</argument>
            </action>
            <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage">
                <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">6</argument>
            </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</referenceContainer>
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: `Design->Layout Update XML` is not possible after 2.3.4.