# Magento 2.3.4 custom layout update - insert different facebook OG on each page

Tags: layout, xml, magento2.3.4

I need to have a different Facebook `OG:IMAGE` for each CMS PAGE.

I found on official documentation how to add a custom layout update on `Magento 2.3.4` --> I've already created this file `cms_page_view_selectable_faq_test1.xml` (where "**faq**" is the cms page URL key, and "**test1**" is the name of the override) inside `mythemeoverride/Magento_Theme/layout/`

The file contains this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page>
    <head>
        <meta property="og:image" content="https://dev.push96.com/media/wysiwyg/push/push96-300x300.png" />
    </head>
</page>
```

I have chosen the override "test1" inside the custom layout update XML of "faq" page, but the result is:

```
*Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'meta', attribute 'property': The attribute 'property' is not allowed.
Line: 1315*
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself, thanks to this link found on google: 
https://olegnax.com/documentation/magento-2/how-to-add-custom-layout-update-in-magento-2-3-4/

The correct syntax is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <head>
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://dev.push96.com/media/wysiwyg/push/push96-300x300.png" />
  </head>
</page>
```