# disable cache for particular category in magento2

Tags: magento2, category, cache

I have a category page with customer specific products, so those products should display based o current customer id. basically caching issues are coming when I'm switching from 1 customer to another customer. How to disable cache only this particular category, or I need to create custom controller and custom product collection?

Comment: Are you using varnish cache or Magento page cache?

Comment: @ZealousWeb yes

Comment: varnish cache..

Answer (score 0):

If using Magento 2.3.4 + you can create specific layout update for that category as defined here:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/303941

and can use cacheable=false in your block in definition or blocks which you do not want to be cached.